# SQL, only one row returned for each jobID

Tags: sql, firebird, greatest-n-per-group

I have this query

```
SELECT
  schedule.JOB_NUMBER, max(schedule_milestone.actual_start_date), milestone.milestone_name
FROM
  schedule 
  inner join
   schedule_milestone on (schedule.schedule_id = schedule_milestone.schedule_id) inner join
   milestone on (milestone.milestone_id = schedule_milestone.milestone_id)
--where schedule.job_number = '024MGV002' using this for testing
group by schedule.job_number, milestone.milestone_name
```

I return the jobNumber, MaxDate and milestone name.

What I want it to return is jobnumber, MaxDate, and milestone name, but I only want one line for each jobnumber. I want the milestone that has the most recent date.

So jobnumber 1234 has 4 different milestones. I want the jobnumber, date and milestone name for the milestone that has the Max date.

Comment: Use a row_number() or rank() to filter only one record..

Comment: @anwaar_hell You should ask what rdbms is OP using. For example mysql doesnt have those functions.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: but MySQL is more or less the only DBMS left that doesn't support [modern SQL](http://use-the-index-luke.com/de/blog/2015-02/modern-sql)

Comment: @Juan..yes i have to ask for ..but it was just a thought..

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza - Well.. OP should say that to start with..

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name And yet is the most used tag here with +350k over 149k from sql-server and 45k from postgre

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: it could just mean people have less problems with Postgres than with MySQL ;)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You are right, but that also mean 3 of 5 times you get stuck with questions where cant use `row_number` or `cte` :(

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't using MySQL you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` function

Otherwise

```
SELECT 
      S.JOB_NUMBER
    , SM.actual_start_date
    , M.milestone_name
FROM schedule S
JOIN schedule_milestone SM
  ON S.schedule_id = SM.schedule_id
JOIN milestone M
  ON M.milestone_id = SM.milestone_id
WHERE SM.actual_start_date = (  SELECT MAX(SM.actual_start_date)
                                FROM schedule iS
                                JOIN schedule_milestone iSM
                                  ON iS.schedule_id = iSM.schedule_id
                                JOIN milestone iM
                                  ON iM.milestone_id = iSM.milestone_id   
                                WHERE iS.job_number = S.job_number
                              )
```

Take note this have an issue if multiple milestones share same `start_date` for same `job_number`

Comment: This does seem to be working.  Had to change the first WHERE statement to HAVING.  What can I do if there are multiple milestones that have the same start_date and  job_number?

Comment: You need something else to tell the difference so you can select the `MAX`. Usually use `TIME STAMP` instead of date.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (
Select JOB_NUMBER,dt,milestone_name,row_number() over (partition by JOB_NUMBER order by dt  desc ) as rownm
from (
SELECT
  schedule.JOB_NUMBER as JOB_NUMBER, milestone.milestone_name, max(schedule_milestone.actual_start_date) as dt
FROM
  schedule   schedule
  inner join
   schedule_milestone schedule_milestone
   on (schedule.schedule_id = schedule_milestone.schedule_id) 
   inner join
   milestone milestone on 
   (milestone.milestone_id = schedule_milestone.milestone_id)
group by schedule.job_number, milestone.milestone_name))
where rownm=1;
```

Comment: `qualify` is non-standard SQL. Which DBMS supports that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ..it is in teradata and oracle11g

Comment: Oracle doesn't have that.

Comment: yes my bad...do not know much about oracle but i guess second works for most of db except where row_number is not there...

Comment: This is SQL.  Both of these give me an error on the 2nd SELECT?

Comment: Still shows error on line 1 character 17, which is the Select inside the first (

Comment: I am using SQL server

Comment: Actually, no.  It is a Firebird DB.

Comment: Firebird does not (yet) have window functions. Only the upcoming version 3.0 will

Comment: @daniel what version of firebird? v3 will support `row_number`